# encodlistknown=findencoding(images) encode=face_recognition.face_encodings(img)[0] Indexerror:list index out of range

Tags: python-3.8

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 
import face_recognition
import os
 
path='C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\Saved Pictures'
images=[]
classnames=[]
mylist=os.listdir(path)
print(mylist)

for cl in mylist:
    curimg=cv2.imread(f'{path}/{cl}')
    images.append(curimg)
    classnames.append(os.path.splitext(cl)[0])
    print(classnames)

def findencoding(images):
    encodelist=[]
    for img in images:
        img=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        encode=face_recognition.face_encodings(img)[0]
        encodelist.append(encode)
        return encodelist
encodelistknown=findencoding(images)
print(len(encodelistknown))


cap= cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while True:
    success,img=cap.read()
    imgs=cv2.resize(img,(0,0),None,0.25,0.25)
    imgs=cv2.cvtColor(imgs,cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)

    facescurfram=face_recognition.face_locations(imgs)
    encodescurframe=face_recognition.face_encodings(imgs,facescurfram)

    for encodeface,faceloc in zip(encodescurframe,facescurfram):
        mathches=face_recognition.compare_faces(encodelistknown,encodeface)
        facedis=face_recognition.face_distance(encodelistknown,encodeface)
        print(facedis)
        mathchindex=np.argmin(facedis)

        if mathches[mathchindex]:
            name=classnames[mathchindex].upper()
            print(name)

            y1,x2,y2,x1=faceloc
            y1,x2,y2,x1=y1*4,x2*4,y2*4,x1*4
            cv2.rectangle(img,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(0,255,0),2)
            cv2.rectangle(img,(x1,y2-35),(x2,y2),(0,255,0),cv2.FILLED)
            cv2.putText(img,name,(x1+6,y2-6),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX,1,(255,255,255))

    cv2.imshow('webcam',img)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

the error is
traceback(most recent call last)
file "c:/users/Admin/desktop/python/myalarm.py",line 25,in 
encodlistknown=findencoding(images)
file "c:/users/Admin/desktop/python/myalarm.py",line 22,in 
encode=face_recognition.face_encodings(img)[0]
Indexerror:list index out of range
1.

---

Comment: my question is This error occurs only when I add a new photo to the file

Comment: Your question is not according to the `Stacjoverflow` guidelines. Your title should be clear and mention the problem statement clearly instead of code or error trace. Please carefully read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your question according to the guidelines.

Comment: Also, please don't write question in comments. Problem statement should be in your question post.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add one more line  (an `if` statement) to the `findencoding` function:

```
 def findencoding(images):
     encodelist=[]
     for img in images:
         img=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
         encode=face_recognition.face_encodings(img)
         if len(encode) > 0:
             encodelist.append(encode[0])
         return encodelist
```